# Which signature spell is the fastest for generating Flashes of Insight?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Wizard’s [Arcane Dynamo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/arcane-dynamo) skill description reads:

> When you deal damage with a Signature spell you may gain a Flash of Insight.

The “may” is very vague. What is the actual chance? And more importantly, which skill may ultimately generate Flashes of Insight faster? Also, is there any runes / passives / item selection which will make the generation even faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spell best suited for this is **Shock Pulse** with the rune **Living Lightning**.

The spell has an insane amount of hits/second, however each hit deals low amounts of damage , but it adds up to the same DPS as any other spell doing the same amount of weapon damage percentage.

Combine **Living Lightning** with items that improve **Attack Speed** and you will fire an insane amount of attacks per second, with each attack producing lots of hits/second. If you fire off several Living Lightnings, you will regenate 5 Flashes of Insight in a few milliseconds after you've casted your non-signature spell.

The skill: http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/shock-pulse
A video showing the skill in action:

They use **Shock Pulse** and **Living Lightning** with a rune that reduces cooldowns by 1 second for every critical hit. You gain lots of critical hits with Living Lightning without critical hit gear, imagine what you get if you gear up correctly!

**NOTE:** I am not sure the above build works anymore, changes were made recently, but **Living Lightning** was unaffected.

Comment: I was using Living Lightning but I don't think it works that way anymore. It seems to only give you 1 second off cooldown for any single Living Lightning pulse that crits, not for each time it crits.

Comment: Note that this answer is no longer accurate as Arcane Dynamo has been changed to `whenever you cast a Signature spell` from `whenever you deal damage with a Signature spell`.

Answer (score 2):

Arcane Dynamo has since been changed to

> When you **cast** a Signature Spell, you gain a Flash of Insight.

Now, causing damage with a Signature spell does not grant Flashes of Insight. However, there is a 100% chance of gaining a stack of Flash of Insight on cast. As such, gaining stacks of Flash of Insight now relies entirely on attack speed and whatever Signature spell you choose has absolutely no effect on the efficiency of gaining stacks of Flash of Insight.

Answer (score 0):

How fast you attack with your signature spell is based on your attack speed.

As such, unless one signature spell hitting multiple enemies counts as more than one instance of dealing damage, there is no difference between different spell abilities.

The actual chance is unfortunately not something that can be determined precisely, and even a vague estimate would take quite a bit of dedicated testing to try to establish a percent chance.

In summary, other than increasing your attack speed, there is very little you can do to affect how often this passive is triggered.