# What is so special about Living Lightning (wizard skill)?

Tags: diablo-iii

Let me try to understand. Only 20% damage. There are other skills that hit much harder than  that.

Yet. I've heard many people recommend it.

WHat advantage does it have? What is it for?

Comment: Incidentally, the Game Guide has been updated for 1.04, and it says Living Lightning does 37% damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69489/20456) answer:

> The spell best suited for this is Shock Pulse with the rune Living Lightning.
>
> The spell has an insane amount of hits/second, however each hit deals low amounts of damage , but it adds up to the same DPS as any other spell doing the same amount of weapon damage percentage.
>
> Combine Living Lightning with items that improve Attack Speed and you will fire an insane amount of attacks per second, with each attack producing lots of hits/second. If you fire off several Living Lightnings, you will regenate 5 Flashes of Insight in a few milliseconds after you've casted your non-signature spell.

So the attack speed ensures that the low damage is not a hindrance; the advantage to using Living Lightning is the super fast attack speed. This allows all the proc chances to regenerate your Flashes of Insight much quicker, crit, or anything else that's based off proc chances.

Comment: It was used a lot in CM builds before the crit triggering got nerfed

Comment: In CM build does this still work?

Comment: Actually the proc rate is so low too.